# Copy one element of an array into another array based on matching value - logic app

Tags: arrays, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to copy one element of an array into another array using a matching `id` element which exists in both arrays. I am building the solution in a logic app.

**Machines Array sample:**

```
"value": [
        {
            "id": "1e5bc9d7e413ddd7902c2932e418702b84d0cc07",
            "computerDnsName": "mymachine1.contoso.com",
            "firstSeen": "2018-08-02T14:55:03.7791856Z",
            "lastSeen": "2018-08-02T14:55:03.7791856Z",
            "osPlatform": "Windows10" "Windows11",
            "version": "1709",
            "osProcessor": "x64",
            "lastIpAddress": "172.17.230.209",
            "lastExternalIpAddress": "167.220.196.71",
            "osBuild": 18209,
            "healthStatus": "Active",
            "rbacGroupId": 140,
            "rbacGroupName": "The-A-Team",
            "riskScore": "Low",
            "exposureLevel": "Medium",
            "isAadJoined": true,
            "aadDeviceId": "80fe8ff8-2624-418e-9591-41f0491218f9",
            "machineTags": [ "test tag 1", "test tag 2" ]
        }
        ...
    ]
```

**Vulnerabilities Array:**

```
"value": [
    {
        "id": "5afa3afc92a7c63d4b70129e0a6f33f63a427e21-_-CVE-2020-6494-_-microsoft-_-edge_chromium-based-_-81.0.416.77-_-",
        "cveId": "CVE-2020-6494",
        "machineId": "5afa3afc92a7c63d4b70129e0a6f33f63a427e21",
        "fixingKbId": null,
        "productName": "edge_chromium-based",
        "productVendor": "microsoft",
        "productVersion": "81.0.416.77",
        "severity": "Low"
    },
    {
        "id": "7a704e17d1c2977c0e7b665fb18ae6e1fe7f3283-_-CVE-2016-3348-_-microsoft-_-windows_server_2012_r2-_-6.3.9600.19728-_-3185911",
        "cveId": "CVE-2016-3348",
        "machineId": "7a704e17d1c2977c0e7b665fb18ae6e1fe7f3283",
        "fixingKbId": "3185911",
        "productName": "windows_server_2012_r2",
        "productVendor": "microsoft",
        "productVersion": "6.3.9600.19728",
        "severity": "Low"
    },
    ...
]
```

So for each item in the vulnerabilities array I would like the `computerDNSName` field included if the `id` value matches.

I have tried to use the 'union' function but this just joins both arrays together.

My goal is to output everything in the vulnerabilities array with the `computerDnsName` included for each item.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this using the [filter operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations?tabs=consumption#filter-array-action):

For each of the values in the vulnerabilities table, I filtered on the machines array where the `machineId` was equal to the `id` in the vulnerabilities table.

I then take the output from the filter `outputs('GetMachineName')['Body'][0]['computerDnsName']` and the other values i want from the original `foreach` loop and append them to a string variable. Since there should only ever be one value returned in the filter I can specify item `[0]` everytime.

This looks like the below:

[image: Logic app Steps]

Answer (score 0):

If you're not wanting to take the looping approach and, depending on the size of your array, will take longer, you should look into using the `Advanced Data Operations` connector with the `Join` operation.

[image: Join]

You can perform an inner (or outer if need be) join and then filter on the results to only include the records that you desire (if required).

It makes it very easy and reduces the technical debt.